# ITC Avant Garde Gothic font support in firefox not supported in chrome?

Tags: css, font-awesome

Am changed font family for my h2 section is ITC  Avant Garde Gothic but it worked in firefox but not support in firefox.

My code,

```
section.about-section h2 {
text-align: left;
font-size: 40px;
margin-bottom: 30px;
font-weight: bold;
font-family: ITC  Avant Garde Gothic , LT;
font-stretch:Regular;
 }
```

Font face using url
[Font face](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css)

Please give my solution what's wrong in my above code declare font for ITC  Avant Garde Gothic.

Comment: Are you using the font locally or via @font-face? If the latter, show that code and identify the source of the font file(s). Explain how Font Awesome is related or remove the tag. Explain what “not support in firefox” (which should probably refer to Chrome instead) means – was the text shown badly, or in the LT font, whatever it is?

Comment: thanx for your reply,am using font face please check above my font face link. ITC  Avant Garde Gothic font not supported in chrome.My text not changed that ITC  Avant Garde Gothic.

Answer (score 0):

Might be font file unsupported extension. WOFF is widely supported in FF. Try convert your ITC font-family to web font friendly by using [fontsquirrel.com](http://fontsquirrel.com)